# How to use insert UUID into MYSQL table Binary(16) using prepared statments

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with how to use UUID for mysql php prepared statements, it keeps giving me errors

The user_id is set to binary(16) on my mysql 5.6, on phpmyadmin
full Function
is there a way I could make this work,

```
function create()
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " SET 
user_id = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-','')),
name = :name,
email = :email,
password = :password";

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);

    $this->name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    $this->password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);

    $password_hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password_hash);
    

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
        echo($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    return false;
}
```

The create function is used here

```
$user->name = $data->name;
$user->email = $data->email;
$user->password = $data->password; 

if(
    !empty($user->name) &&
    !empty($user->email) &&
    !empty($user->password)&&
    $user->create()
   
){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "User was created."));
}else{
        
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array($user->create()));
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user."));
    }
```

the error the

```
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
```

gives is

Array
(
[0] => HY000
[1] => 1270
[2] => Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'
)
[false]{"message":"Unable to create user."}

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags` < scrap all of those, they're not doing much for preventing sql injection. Your prepared statement takes care of that. Plus, you shouldn't be manipulating passwords in any way. `password_hash()` takes care of that and you could be doing more harm than good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that you're mixing incompatible collations in your replace function call.

This is generated because your connection is set to use `utf8_unicode_ci` collaction, while `UUID` function returns `utf8_general_ci` string. If you want to use that statement you must add a collation conversion like:

`UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID() COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, '-', ''))`

**BUT**

Think twice about using uuid function like this as `UUID()` and `UUID_SHORT()` can make your life harder when setting up replication.

Prefer generating your uuid in PHP (via [uuid extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid), [ramsey/uuid library](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) or [symfony uid component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html)) and set it as query parameter. This avoids the eventual replication issues and let you know the value of the uuid without querying the database again.

Comment: Thanks, UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID() COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, '-', '')) works I'll check up on the other libraries(have to find a way to get composer on my shared host) Thanks again.